# Trying to bind on change even to file select input doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind on change to file input i read around and the following suppose to work but doesn't:

```
 <input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="Uploadthisfile" />
```

This is my file input

```
$("#Uploadthisfile").change(function() { 
  alert('some message');
});
```

This is how i am trying to bind it.

Am i doing something wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wrapping it within a document.ready function?  It works fine in the fiddle below

```
$(function(){  // <-- short form of below - waits for dom to load before -- 
               // elements have to exist in dom before trying to bind them
   $("#Uploadthisfile").change(function() { 
      alert('some message');
   });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#Uploadthisfile").change(function() { 
      alert('some message');
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/C6RZn/

Comment: its already in a document ready yea. weird cant seem to make it work.. and its so simple

Comment: It's working fine in the fiddle also.. are there any errors inside your console?

Comment: found the problem and it was totally my stupidity not finding it before ... i forgot i load many more of those in a php loop with exact same ID..

Answer (score 0):

```
//Upload the File and Convert into base64 string
$('#Uploadthisfile').live('change', function () {

var fileList = this.files;
var file = fileList[0];
var r = new FileReader();
r.onload = function () {
    var binimage = r.result;
    binimage1 = binimage.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '');
    var imag = "<img " + "src='" + 
        "data:image/jpg;base64," + binimage1 + "' style='width:100px'/>";
    $("#partial1").html(imag);

};
r.readAsDataURL(file);
// r.readAsBinaryString(file);
//r.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```